# Getting a list of tweets using a hashtag in PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm attempting to use Twitter's API, which to me seems hugely overcomplicated. I want to simply get a list of tweets that include a hashtag ('#test' for now), along with the username.

This is what I have so far using Abraham's TwitterOAuth:

```
<?php
$token = 'MY_TOKEN';
$token_secret = 'MY_TOKEN_SECRET';
$consumer_key = 'MY_CONSUMER_KEY';
$consumer_secret = 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET';

require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $token, $token_secret );

$connection->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$connection->ssl_verifypeer = TRUE;
$connection->content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$tweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23test&result_type=recent');

echo $tweets;
?>
```

This produces the error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` in the `echo $tweets;` line.

How do I go about fixing this?

---

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code to `$tweets = $connection->get('search/tweets', ["q" => "#test", "result_type" => "recent"]);` and `var_dump($tweets);` which seems to work. Now I just have to figure out how to parse this.

Comment: You can't echo the object. Use `var_dump($tweets)` to find what data you are looking for.

Comment: @Ali Now I'm getting `object(stdClass)[3] public 'errors' => array (size=1) 0 => object(stdClass)[8] public 'message' => string 'Sorry, that page does not exist' (length=31) public 'code' => int 34`

Comment: I think the url will escape automatically, `change tweets.json?q=%23test&result_type=recent to tweets.json?q=test&result_type=recent` to  `tweets.json?q=#test&result_type=recent to tweets.json?q=test&result_type=recent`